# Debug with Embedded Felix

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, osgi, apache-felix

How can I debug a bundle when running felix embedded in a web application?

I'm currently using Eclipse.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't that much special about debugging a Felix bundle, or debugging any piece of code. Just set up your web application for debugging as you usually do (e.g., use remote debugging with `-Xdebug`), place some breakpoints in Eclipse, and connect the debugger.

Comment: To add to @Angelo's answer; launch the web container with: `-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005`    Then in Eclipse select Debug -> Remote Java Application -> new and set the connect properties to host:localhost port:5005